# How to disable cell on grid according to checkbox status extJs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs6

I need to disable some cells according checkbox status is changed.
I added a listener to a checkbox column:

```
listeners: {
    checkchange: function( me , rowIndex , checked , record , e , eOpts) {
        var row = me.getView().getRow(rowIndex);
        var columnIndex = Ext.getCmp('MyColumnIdToDisable').fullColumnIndex;
        Ext.get(row.childNodes[columnIndex]).setDisabled=!checked;
    }        
}
```

But I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Ext.get(...).setDisabled is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`this.disabledCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-disabledCls) I have already example which does probably the same as you need. It disables particular cell.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lvm

```
onCheckcolumnCheckChange: function (checkcolumn, rowIndex, checked, record, eOpts) {
    // we need to get a grids view
    var view = Ext.first('#MySpecialGridId').getView();
    var cell = view.getCell(rowIndex,1);

    if (checked) {
        // add disabled cls -> disabled
        cell.addCls(this.disabledCls);
    }else{
        // remove the disabled cls -> enabled
        cell.removeCls(this.disabledCls)
    }
}
```

Comment: I encountered a problem using addCls, when I click on the first checkbox the second is blocked, but if I use the TAB then I can check the disabled checkbox

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro I see. I never noticed it. But you can use event http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Check.html#event-beforecheckchange if this even returns false, the edit is not done. So in this event function you can chcek position / if the cell hasCls disabled and not allow the dit.